# How to handle 2 ipcRenderer.send calls to 1 ipcMain.on

Tags: angular, electron

Here is the situation.

The database is directly access with nodejs (node-adodb) in main.js. My Angular app send the request and receive the sql result from the db.service. This part is working just fine, but if I have a function like getInfo(), the first returned promise would be the value of the second request. How would you suggest me to handle that situation to avoid that conflicts?

Yes, I could wait for the first call to return and then do the next one, but do you think it could be done differently?

Thanks in advance

Here is the code

main.js

```
ipcMain.on('item:select', (event, sql) => {
  connection
    .query(sql)
    .on('done', function (data) {
      event.sender.send('async-reply', data);
    })
    .on('fail', function (error) {
      event.sender.send("async-reply", error);
    });
});
```

db.service.ts

```
select(sql: string): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ipcRenderer.send('item:select', sql);

    ipcRenderer.on('async-reply', (event, result) => {
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
```

user.ts

```
getInfo() {
  this.userService
    .getUsers()
    .then((value: User[]) => this.users = value);

  this.userService
    .getUserTypes()
    .then((value: UserType[]) => this.userType = value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution that I used:

main.js

```
ipcMain.on('select', (event, type, sql) => {

  const reply = 'reply-select-' + type;

  connection = ADODB.open('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=mydb.mdb;');

  connection
    .query(sql)
    .then((data) => {
      event.sender.send(reply, { status: 0, message: '', data: data });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      event.sender.send(reply, { status: 1, message: error.message, data: {} });
    });
});
```

db.service.ts

```
select(sql: string, selectItem: string): Promise<DbStatus> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ipcRenderer.send('select', selectItem, sql);

      ipcRenderer.on('reply-select-' + selectItem, (event, result: DbStatus) => {
        resolve(result);
      });
    });
  }
```